# RTMP + NGINX + Video.js ERROR The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported

Tags: html, nginx, stream, video.js, rtmp

I'm totally new to this kind of applications, so days ago I followed [this tutorial](https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2013/11/streaming-video-demand-nginx-rtmp-module/) and it worked fine with VLC. But when I tried the web browser check it didn't work.

So I searched for a new solution and found out about Video.js. All the tests that I tried failed, and in the last one, I got the message : **The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported.** The video is in MP4 format, how do I deal with HLS ? Knowing that I tried other scripts that should work fine with MP4 but since Flash is no longer supported it didn't work at all.

My code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>videojs-contrib-hls embed</title>
  
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

  <video-js id="my_video_1" class="vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="268">
    <source src="rtmp://localhost:1935/vod2/test_video.mp4" type="application/x-mpegURL">
  </video-js>
  
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@videojs/http-streaming/dist/videojs-http-streaming.js"></script>
  
  <script>
    var player = videojs('my_video_1');
  </script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Please can you help me, I've been working on this for two weeks now, I've never done this kind of code so please bear with me. Thank you.

Comment: That error msg is the standard msg which can also mean the source file just wasn't found.  e.g. the path or filename specified is incorrect.

Comment: I'm totally new to HLS myself, and I created a minimalist experiment as a learning exercise.  This code might be helpful...similar enough for you to learn sometime from it.  It's deploy on my webserver here:  https://weasel.firmfriends.us/HLS-Pvt-Paul/

Comment: @Dave Thank you I'll try to find the answer and put it here.